# error unknown or unsupported arm architecture

Tags: android, android-ndk, vnc

I am trying to Compile C daemon of oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server available in GitHub, I am facing an error makes me spending lot of time on the same issue, please give me solution on this,
 * while I am giving the command it running and stuck with the error that

> /home/akhil/android/android-ndk-r10_64/build/core/build-binary.mk:448: warning: overriding commands for target `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/simd/asm/armv7'
>   /home/akhil/android/android-ndk-r10_64/build/core/build-binary.mk:448: warning: ignoring old commands for target`obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/simd/asm/armv7'
>   [armeabi] Compile arm    : jpeg <= jidctfst.S
>   In file included from jni/jpeg/jidctfst.S:17:0:
>   /home/akhil/android/android-ndk-r10_64/platforms/android-L/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/cpu-features.h:52:6: error: #error Unknown or unsupported ARM architecture
>    #    error Unknown or unsupported ARM architecture
>         ^
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/jpeg/jidctfst.o] Error 1

here is the epu-feature.h

```
#ifndef _ARM_MACHINE_CPU_FEATURES_H
#define _ARM_MACHINE_CPU_FEATURES_H

#ifndef __ARM_ARCH__
#  if defined __ARM_ARCH_7__   || defined __ARM_ARCH_7A__ || \
    defined __ARM_ARCH_7R__  || defined __ARM_ARCH_7M__
#    define __ARM_ARCH__ 7
#  elif defined __ARM_ARCH_6__   || defined __ARM_ARCH_6J__ || \
    defined __ARM_ARCH_6K__  || defined __ARM_ARCH_6Z__ || \
    defined __ARM_ARCH_6KZ__ || defined __ARM_ARCH_6T2__
#    define __ARM_ARCH__ 6
#  else
#    error Unknown or unsupported ARM architecture
#  endif
#endif

#define  __ARM_HAVE_HALFWORD_MULTIPLY  1

#if __ARM_ARCH__ >= 7
#  define __ARM_HAVE_LDREXD
#endif
#if __ARM_ARCH__ >= 7 && defined __VFP_FP__
#  define __ARM_HAVE_VFP
#endif


#if __ARM_ARCH__ >= 7 && defined __ARM_NEON__
#  define __ARM_HAVE_NEON
#endif

#endif
```

onaip source code is available on git repository :

> https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server

Comment: does following answer worked for you..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will solve if,

- change PLD() to PLD[] ( change to square bracket)
- build with android ndk 32 bit